# C++ Serial COM Port Access

Tags: c++, windows

in uPyCraft IDE or Putty, just sending km.press('a') then it works fine,
but in my C++, i tried to writefile with km.press('a'), it doesn't work.
i can't find what is wrong

[uPyCraft Successfull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJIX2.png)

```
`bool CSerialPort::OpenPort(CString portname)
{
    m_hComm = CreateFile(L"//./" + portname,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        0);
    if (m_hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "INVALID HANDLE" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

bool CSerialPort::WriteByte(const char * bybyte)
{
    byte iBytesWritten = 0;
    if (WriteFile(m_hComm, &bybyte, 1, &m_iBytesWritten, NULL) == 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int main()
{
CSerialPort _serial;

_serial.OpenPort(L"COM4");

_serial.WriteByte("km.press('a')");
}`
```

i tried this,

but it doesn't work, i also check _serial Isn't INVALID HANDLE.

someone help me for sending `"km.press('a')"` to serial

and sending `km.move(0,1)` with using Putty and uPyCraft,

it works fine but

```
string test = "km.move(0,1)";
DWORD dwBytesWritten;
WriteFile(m_hComm,&test,sizeof(test),dwBytesWritten,NULL);
```

it doesn't work. just changing `km.move(0,1)` to `km.move(0,10)`, then i don't know why but it works fine.
what is different with uPyCraft(Putty) and C++?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommstate

Comment: BaudRate : 115200
ByteSize : 8
Parity : 0
StopBits : 1

Comment: In `WriteByte(const char * bybyte)` you take the address of `bybyte` and provide that to `WriteFile` (which means that it will send the wrong byte). You should provide `bybyte` as-is since it's a pointer (to a `char` presumably): `WriteFile(m_hComm, bybyte, ...`. Unrelated: Since the function only sends _one_ `char`, why not take the `char` by value? `WriteByte(char bybyte)`. Then you need `&bybyte` when you send it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TedLyngmo how can i sending string to writebyte(char bybyte)??
just like upycraft km.press('a')

Comment: @김재희 You could change the function to `bool WriteBytes(const void* bybyte, DWORD bytesToWrite) { return WriteFile(m_hComm, bybyte, bytesToWrite, &m_iBytesWritten, NULL) != 0; }` assuming that `m_iBytesWritten` is a `DWORD` member variable.

Comment: You would need to supply the number of bytes to send to the function above of course. If you want an overload for strings, add the function `bool WriteString(const char* str) { return WriteBytes(static_cast<const void*>(str), std::strlen(str)); }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo i don't know why but `WriteString("km.press('a')")` it doesn't work,
i tried this WriteFile Code and it works fine.
`string test = "km.press('a')";
DWORD dwBytesWritten;
WriteFile(m_hComm, &test, sizeof(test), &dwBytesWritten,NULL);`

i don't know how to make a function code for `WriteFile(m_hComm, &test, sizeof(test), &dwBytesWritten,NULL);`

Comment: @김재희 It becomes to messy here in the comments so I added a proper answer instead.

Comment: @김재희 Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, I'm assuming your class definition looks something like this:

```cpp
class CSerialPort {
public:
    bool OpenPort(CString portname);
    bool WriteByte(const char* bybyte);

private:
    HANDLE m_hComm;
    byte m_iBytesWritten;
};
```

- `byte` is not the proper type. `DWORD` is.
- `CString` may be used, but you are using wide string literals anyway so you could just use `CreateFileW`, `std::wstring`s and `std::wstring_view`s.
- `WriteByte` implies that you only want to write one byte - and indeed, your implementation does only write one byte - but it's the wrong byte. It writes one byte out of the memory of the `bybyte` variable, not the memory it points at.

A minor redefinition of the class:

```cpp
#include <string_view> // added header

class CSerialPort {
public:
    // take a `std::wstring` instead
    bool OpenPort(const std::wstring& portname);

    // WriteBytes instead of WriteByte:
    bool WriteBytes(const void* bytesPtr, DWORD bytesToWrite);

    // write both wide and non-wide string_views    
    bool WriteString(std::string_view str);
    bool WriteString(std::wstring_view str);

private:
    HANDLE m_hComm;
    DWORD m_iBytesWritten; // the proper type
};
```

The implementation in the `.cpp` file then becomes:

```cpp
bool CSerialPort::OpenPort(const std::wstring& portname) {
    // Use CreateFileW since you've hardcoded wide string literals anyway:
    m_hComm = CreateFileW((L"//./" + portname).c_str(),
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        0);
    return m_hComm != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}

bool CSerialPort::WriteBytes(const void* bytesPtr, DWORD bytesToWrite)
{
    return
        WriteFile(m_hComm, bytesPtr, bytesToWrite, &m_iBytesWritten, nullptr) != 0;
}

// the WriteString overloads taking string_views pass on the pointer
// and length to `WriteBytes`:
bool CSerialPort::WriteString(std::string_view str) {
    return WriteBytes(str.data(), str.size());
}

bool CSerialPort::WriteString(std::wstring_view str) {
    return WriteBytes(str.data(), str.size() * // wchar_t's are more than 1 byte:
                                  sizeof(std::wstring_view::value_type));
}
```

And your `main` would then use the `WriteString` overload taking a `std::string_view` (by passing a `const char*` to `WriteString`):

```cpp
int main()
{
    CSerialPort _serial;

    if(_serial.OpenPort(L"COM4")) {
        _serial.WriteString("km.press('a')");
    } else {
        std::cerr << "failed opening COM4\n";
    }
}
```

---

Note: The section you added at the end has several errors:

```
string test = "km.move(0,1)";
DWORD dwBytesWritten;
WriteFile(m_hComm,&test,sizeof(test),dwBytesWritten,NULL);
```

- `&test` takes the address of the `std::string` object. You should use `test.c_str()` to get a `const char*` to the first character in the string.
- `sizeof(test)` gets the size of the `std::string` object, not the length of the actual string. You should use `test.size()` instead.
- `dwBytesWritten` is passed by value but the function expects a pointer to a `DWORD` that it can write to. You should use `&dwBytesWritten` instead.

```cpp
WriteFile(m_hComm, test.c_str(), test.size(), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```